# Using Devise, how can I set the root page to not redirect to the "sign_in" page if the user is logged out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I would like to populate the root page with certain items from my database and just have a link to sign in somewhere on the page. Basically I don't want to make the content exclusive to those who are logged in.

Answer (score 2):

In your root controller, just add:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Example:

```
class RootController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    #some logic here
  end
end
```

You can also limit it to just the index action:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]
```

Good luck!